# Yii Join query result not as expected

Tags: yii, inner-join

```
select users.*, user_address.*, user_kyc_details.* , user_nominee.*,  user_bank_details.* 
from users, user_address, user_kyc_details, user_nominee, user_bank_details
where user_address.user_id=users.id and user_kyc_details.user_id=users.id and user_nominee.user_id=users.id and  user_bank_details.user_id=users.id
```

how to run this directly in  $query->createCommand(); as parameter i tried it but it doen't work

The above query works fine and gives expected result but when i use join  using Yii like given below it gives me strange results(i.e. doesn't join on appropriate id and user_id)

$query = new Query;

```
    $query->select([
    'users.*',
    'user_address.*'
    'user_kyc_details.*',
    'user_nominee.*',
    'user_bank_details.*'
    ])
    ->from('users')
    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'user_address','user_address.user_id = users.id')
    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'user_kyc_details','users.id =user_kyc_details.user_id')
    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'user_nominee','users.id =user_nominee.user_id')
    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'user_bank_details','users.id =user_bank_details.user_id');

    $command = $query->createCommand();
    $data = $command->queryAll();
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: select users.*, user_address.*, user_kyc_details.* , user_nominee.*,  user_bank_details.* from users, user_address, user_kyc_details, user_nominee, user_bank_details where user_address.user_id=users.id and user_kyc_details.user_id=users.id and user_nominee.user_id=users.id 
        and  user_bank_details.user_id=users.id

Answer (score 0):

If you have alreade the query  you do directly in command

```
$sql = "select 
            users.*
          , user_address.*
          , user_kyc_details.* 
          , user_nominee.*
          ,  user_bank_details.* 
         from users, user_address, user_kyc_details, user_nominee, user_bank_details
         where user_address.user_id=users.id 
            and user_kyc_details.user_id=users.id 
              and user_nominee.user_id=users.id 
                and  user_bank_details.user_id=users.id";


$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand( $sql );
$command->queryAll();
```